# Aggregate "once-only" whether 1 or 2 rows in join

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to run an aggregate query where a join can find 0, 1 or 2 rows in the join table.
I want to aggregate "once-only" regardless of whether the join finds 1 or 2 matching rows.

Minimal example.

```
+--------------+--------+-----------+
| container_id | thing  | alternate |
+--------------+--------+-----------+
|            1 | box    |         0 |
|            1 | box    |         1 |
|            1 | hat    |         0 |
|            2 | monkey |         0 |
|            3 | monkey |         1 |
|            3 | chair  |         1 |
+--------------+--------+-----------+

+--------------+------+
| container_id | uses |
+--------------+------+
|            1 |    3 |
|            2 |    1 |
|            3 |    2 |
+--------------+------+
```

You can see that 'box' is associated with container_id number 1 twice. Once with alternate=0 and once with alternate=1.

```
SELECT 
    thing, COUNT(DISTINCT ct.container_id) AS occurrencs, SUM(uses) AS uses 
FROM 
    container_thing AS ct 
INNER JOIN 
    container_usage AS cu ON cu.container_id = ct.container_id 
GROUP BY 
    thing
```

gives:

```
+--------+------------+------+
| thing  | occurrencs | uses |
+--------+------------+------+
| box    |          1 |    6 |
| chair  |          1 |    2 |
| hat    |          1 |    3 |
| monkey |          2 |    3 |
+--------+------------+------+
```

but I really want is:

```
+--------+------------+------+
| thing  | occurrencs | uses |
+--------+------------+------+
| box    |          1 |    3 |
| chair  |          1 |    2 |
| hat    |          1 |    3 |
| monkey |          2 |    3 |
+--------+------------+------+
```

I want 3 as the value for uses in the first row because 'box' was in containers that were used a total of three times. Because of the 'alternate' column I get 6 for that value. **Can I either join differently or group by differently or express in the SUM expression to only SUM once for each distinct thing regardless of the value of alternate?**

(Note that a thing can appear in a container with alternate, without alternate or both.)

SQL necessary to set up the minimal example:

```
-- Set up db
CREATE DATABASE sumtest;
USE sumtest;

-- Set up tables
CREATE TABLE container (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE container_thing (container_id INT, thing NVARCHAR(10), alternate BOOLEAN);
CREATE TABLE container_usage (container_id INT, uses INT);

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO container (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO container_thing (container_id, thing, alternate) VALUES (1, 'box', FALSE), (1, 'box', TRUE), (1, 'hat', FALSE), (2, 'monkey', FALSE), (3, 'monkey', TRUE), (3, 'chair', TRUE);
INSERT INTO container_usage VALUES (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2);

-- Query
SELECT thing, COUNT(DISTINCT ct.container_id) AS occurrencs, SUM(uses) AS uses FROM container_thing AS ct INNER JOIN container_usage AS cu ON cu.container_id = ct.container_id GROUP BY thing;
```

Comment: update your question and add  also the expected  result as tabular text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this by only selecting `DISTINCT` values of `container_id` and `thing` from `container_thing` in a derived table and `JOIN`ing that to `container_usage`:

```
SELECT thing, COUNT(ct.container_id) AS occurrences, SUM(uses) AS uses 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT container_id, thing
      FROM container_thing) AS ct 
INNER JOIN container_usage AS cu ON cu.container_id = ct.container_id 
GROUP BY thing;
```

Output

```
thing   occurrences     uses
box     1               3
chair   1               2
hat     1               3
monkey  2               3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=51f0452424ac09acef9f5dd633410c23)

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there any difference (performance-wise?) between using DISTINCT in the subquery or using GROUP BY as in @scaisEdge's answer?

Comment: Performance wise there probably won't be much in it; it would depend on your data as to which ended up being the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the use ..  then you should not  perform the sum in join ..  because the join produce T1xT2 rows for each macthing  ON clause
where N is the number of row from table1  and M is the number of rows from table2 so in the case of box you have 2 x 1 with value 3 = 6.

for avoid this you should join  container_usage  with the subqiery for aggreated  result for count of container_thing

```
select t.thing, t.count_container,  cu.uses 
from (
  SELECT thing,  container_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ct.container_id)  count_container
  FROM  container_thing 
  GROUP BY thing, container_id
) t 
inner join  container_usage AS cu ON cu.container_id = t.container_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there any difference (performance-wise?) between using GROUP BY in the subquery or using DISTINCT as in @Nick's answer?

Comment: for performace are pratically are the same  ..   but  the result for COUNT(DISTINCT ct.container_id) and group by  is not  the same for distinct  ..  (in this case return same value but not ever )  ...  you have edited my answer in wrong way

Comment: Oh, sorry. For the minimal example and in my actual problem the count_container column doesn't seem to do anything so I removed it. I really just wanted to fix the typo in "selet" but SO requires at least 6 characters to change so I did that too :)

Comment: Is one of DISTINCT or GROUP BY more correct? When do the results differ?

Comment: .. I can answer  just at your question  ..  and i presume taht the count distinct for you is relevevant ..

Comment: if you use aggreagtion function you can't use DISTINCT but you must use group by .. If you don't use aggreation function and want avoid duplicated  rows  you need distinct clause  ..  .. distinct clause just reduce duplicated  rows ..  don't allow aggreagtion function ..  .. and if your query  involve aggregation function  require  group by  ...

Comment: and why downvoting ??